# Define the file location in the same folder as the python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to define the file paths of the following files which are in the same location as the python file. All the questions from the google searches deal with opening the file but not getting the location. How can this be done?

```
abaqus_input_template_path = '/30_30_0-8.inp'
cost_path = '/CostEstimation_001.xlsx'
pole_option_path = '/지주.xlsx'
chord_option_path = '/상,하현재 .xlsx'
diagonal_option_path = '/사재.xlsx'
element_label_by_type_path = '/Element label number by Type.xlsx'
tunnel_png_path = '/tunnel.png'
mip_obj_path = '/mip_res.obj'
```

Edit:

```
test =project(abaqus_input_template_path,cost_path,pole_option_path,chord_option_path,
             diagonal_option_path,element_label_by_type_path,tunnel_png_path,mip_obj_path)
```

The location is used in another function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide absolute paths

```
import os

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # Gets directory path of the current python module
cost_path = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR , 'CostEstimation_001.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you import the os module, there are a few functions that can help you:
os.path.abspath, which gets you something's path if it's already in the same directory, and
os.walk, which searches for it and gives you it's location.

```
import os
exe = 'something.exe'
#if the exe just in current dir
print os.path.abspath(exe)
# output
# D:\python\note\something.exe

#if we need find it first
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'D:\python'):
    for name in files:
        if name == exe:
            print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name))

# output
# D:\python\note\something.exe
```

Comment: The path has '\' instead of '/'

Comment: @devinxxd
Sorry- was away from my computer. Have you tried converting your ‘/‘s to ‘\’s or converting my ‘\’s to ‘/‘s?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `__file__`.

Create a script called `try_this.py` and run it:

```
from pathlib import Path

print(__file__)
print(Path(__file__).parent)
print(Path(__file__).parent / 'some_other_file.csv')
```

The result should be something like:

```
C:/Location/try_this.py
C:\Location
C:\Location\some_other_file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

For example to find a directory named mattermost in root directory you can use following.

```
sudo find / -name "mattermost" -type d
```

for finding file location

```
sudo find / -name "mattermost" -type f
```

If you want to get the file locations in your script use os module as suggested by [grismar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4390160/grismar)